# PHPUnit testing WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, testing, unit-tests

Using answers on this site and from other resources, I have started writing my next plugin using PHPUnit tests and the WordPress test environment.  Distilling down what I have in my plugin's `bootstrap.php`:

```
define( 'WP_TESTS_DIR', 'pathToMyWordPressTestsFromSVN');
define( 'TEST_PLUGIN_FILE', 'pathToMyPlugin/myPlugin.php' );
require_once WP_TESTS_DIR . 'includes/functions.php';
require WP_TESTS_DIR . 'includes/bootstrap.php';

function _manually_load_plugin() {
    require TEST_PLUGIN_FILE;
    if(is_plugin_active(TEST_PLUGIN_FILE)){
        echo "PLUGIN IS LOADED AND WORKING!!!!";
    }
}
tests_add_filter( 'muplugins_loaded', '_manually_load_plugin' );

// Normally you'd find "require WP_TESTS_DIR . 'includes/bootstrap.php';" down here...
```

In essentially every example, the WordPress test environment `bootstrap.php` is loaded last.

This seems strange because if I load it earlier, I get access to functions like `is_plugin_active` which I imagine will be useful when testing plugins that require others...and bailing out if the requirements aren't loaded for some reason.

**Is there a reason the test environment is bootstrapped at the end...other than habit/convention?**

Comment: Could you possibly link to the resources and reference materials you've been using to set this up?

Comment: It took me several days knitting together things from the Codex, tutorials, random GitHub projects and so on.  My notes are pretty good, but not electronic (yet).  Let me see if I can take the current project and clean it up to share on Github.

Comment: That, sir, would be amazing.

Comment: I posted my first working version as a github project: [wordtest on GitHub](https://github.com/mbakaitis/wordtest).  There are a ton of things on my list of improvements...but for now, it's better than nothing and it's easy to add new plugins/themes as needed.

Comment: Wow, this is really nice. I wish there was a better way to make people aware of this project's existence.

Comment: Thanks!  At the moment, it's really pretty rough and there's a ton to do both with improving the harness and with the documentation.  If you have any suggestions or have problem using it or figuring out what I did, feel free to leave an issue/comment on the GitHub project.

Comment: I actually ended up using WordPress's internal testing bootstrap file per [this tutorial](http://codesymphony.co/writing-wordpress-plugin-unit-tests/), but I'm definitely going to keep this tool in mind for future projects / other people trying to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason the WordPress test bootstrap is loaded at the end is precisely because it [loads WordPress](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/bootstrap.php#L83):

```
// Load WordPress
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-settings.php';
```

If you don't hook your function to load your plugin to `'muplugins_loaded'` *before* including the bootstrap, your plugin won't be loaded with WordPress. In most cases that will mean that your plugin won't get set up properly (e.g., `'init'` will have already been fired before your plugin's functions get hooked up).

As far as checking for dependencies, you could probably do that by hooking into the `'plugins_loaded'` action:

```
function _check_for_dependencies() {
    if ( ! is_plugin_active( 'some-plugin/some-plugin.php' ) ) {
        exit( 'Some Plugin must be active to run the tests.' . PHP_EOL );
    }
}
tests_add_filter( 'plugins_loaded', '_check_for_dependencies' );
```

Or, you can just let WordPress' bootstrap load completely and check for your dependencies after it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Try-and-fail experimentation after asking showed that moving it up was causing errors in tests I was writing.  Now it makes sense why that was happening.